# Что за скрытое пространство в Mac OS?

Tags: macos, hdd

У меня начало деваться место на диске. Купил программу DaisyDisk и она показала такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял, (1) - это сама система, а что такое (2)? это же не система?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы нажмете на этот пункт меню то увидите приблизительно такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. ***purgeable space*** - в основном локальные снимки Time Machine, а также файлы подкачки, спящие образы и другие временные системные файлы.
2. ***other volumes*** - вложенные тома на том же физическом диске, которые совместно используют свой пул свободного пространства (новая функция APFS). Этот элемент может включать некоторые невидимые системные тома и тома, которые вы создали сами.
3. ***still hidden*** - окончательный остаток неучтенного пространства, как правило, состоит из: Домашних папок других пользователей на том же Mac, если есть,системные вещи, такие как указатель Spotlight, версии документов и т. Д. затраты на файловую систему (2-3 ГБ - это нормально для загрузочного диска)

[Вот](https://daisydiskapp.com/manual/4/en/Topics/HiddenSpace.html) статья первоисточник и [обсуждение](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8619010) данное проблемы.